# Why such way to change a list doesn't change anything?

Tags: python, list

I have the next test task:

```
arr = [4,3,2,1]
arr[0], arr[arr[0]-1] = arr[arr[0]-1], arr[0]
print(arr)
```

I'd expect the result as [1,3,2,4] as we assign new values to elements of the list. But it gives the result as the initially [4,3,2,1].

Why does it work in this way? Why does it change not the list?

If to make it in the next way:
`arr[0], arr[3] = 1 , 4`

it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at order in which interpreter evaluates

`arr[0], arr[arr[0]-1] = arr[arr[0]-1], arr[0]`

So first it evaluates RHS from left to right and above line is equivalent to

`arr[0], arr[arr[0]-1] = 1, 4`

Now it start to evaluate from left to right the LHS and assign 1 to `arr[0]`, at that point `arr` is `[1, 3, 2, 1]`

it now evaluates `arr[arr[0]-1]` and gets `arr[1-1]` or `arr[0]`. So it assign 4 to index 0. And the result is `[4, 3, 2, 1]`

Note, it will work if you swap the element, e.g.

```
arr = [4,3,2,1]
arr[arr[0]-1], arr[0]  = arr[0], arr[arr[0]-1]
print(arr)
```

output

```
[1, 3, 2, 4]
```

However, this complicated indexing doesn't make sense IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the way you are assigning two things.

```
arr[0], arr[arr[0]-1] = arr[arr[0]-1], arr[0]
```

What it does is it calculates the RHS first as `1, 4` and now, on LHS, first `arr[0]` is assigned as `1`, and now it uses this `arr[0]=1` to solve `arr[arr[0]-1]` which again turns out as `arr[0]` which gets assigned to 4.
**So basically, it does two tasks in sequence, which cancels the overall operation (for the array you have defined).**

Try using `arr = [4,2,5,3]` to see the effect of what I am conveying. For some values, it will also lead to Index out of range errors.